# Checking if a graph is at-least-one-way-connected

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, big-o, graph-algorithm

A directed graph is called '*at-least-one-way-connected*' if, for every two nodes `u` and `v` in the graph, there's either a path from `u` to `v` or a path from `v` to `u` (or both).
Is there an algorithm of time complexity `O(m + n)` for solving this problem?

Answer (score 6):

To build up to the overall solution, let's begin by with a much simpler version of this problem. Suppose that you knew that the input graph was a directed acyclic graph (DAG). How might you solve the problem in this case? Well, if the DAG had two different source nodes, then it couldn't be at-least-one-way-connected (ALOWC), since there wouldn't be a path from one of those source nodes to the other. If the DAG does have a single source node, then there's a path from that node to every other node in the DAG. That means that the overall graph is ALOWC if every other pair of nodes in the graph are ALOWC, which we can determine by removing that source node and recursively looking at the graph we have left. In other words, our algorithm would look something like this:

```
while (the graph has more than one node) {
    if (the graph has more than one source node) return false;
    else find and remove a source node;
}
```

One way to implement this algorithm efficiently is to begin by finding a node of indegree 0. From there, we can remove it from the graph and decrement the indegree of each of its successors. We can then see, of those remaining successors, which have indegree 0 and proceed from there. Here's some pseudocode:

```
/* Compute indegrees. */
for (each node u) {
    u.indegree = 0;
}
for (each edge (u, v) in the graph) {
    v.indegree++;
}

/* Find a node with indegree 0. */
Node source = null;
for (each node u in the graph) {
    if (u.indegree == 0) {
        if (source != null) return false; // Two sources
        source = u;
    }
}

/* Repeatedly remove the source node, update indegrees, and find the
 * next node to process.
 */
while (there is more than one node) {
    /* Simulate removing the source node by decrementing the indegree
     * of each of its children.
     */
    Node next = null;
    for (each edge (source, v)) {
        v.indegree--;
        if (v.indegree == 0) {
            if (next != null) return false; // Two sources discovered
            next = v;
        }
    }

    source = next;
}
return true;
```

This algorithm runs in time O(m + n): it takes time O(n) to set the counts to 0, time O(m) to initialize them to the proper values, and time O(m + n) for the loop, since each node is set as the source at most once and each edge is visited at most once.

So now we have an algorithm that solves this problem for DAGs, but what about general graphs? The good news is that the more general version of this problem can be converted into the problem on DAGs by looking at the [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) of the graph and graph's [condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component#Definitions). (If you haven't seen these concepts before, I think your best bet would be to search around for a good explanation of them, since I don't think I can give a complete explanation here).

The key insight is the following: a graph G is ALOWC if and only if its *condensation* is *also* ALOWC. To see why this is, first suppose that the condensation is ALOWC, and then pick any two nodes u and v in G. If u and v are strongly connected, then there's a path from u to v, and so they're ALOWC. On the other hand, if u and v are not strongly connected, then since the condensation is ALOWC, there's either a path from the SCC containing u to the SCC containing v or vice-versa in the condensation, and that path gives a path from u to v (or vice-versa) in the original graph G.

On the other hand, if G is ALOWC, then if we form its condensation, the resulting DAG must be ALOWC, since given any two SCCs C1 and C2 in the DAG, if we pick some node u in C1 and some node v in C2 from G, then there's a path either from u to v or v to u, and therefore in the condensation there's a path from C1 to C2 or vice-versa.

So this gives a very clean O(m + n)-time algorithm for this problem:

1. Compute the condensation of the graph G using a standard linear-time algorithm like [Tarjan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) or [Kosaraju's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm).
2. Use the above algorithm for DAGs to check whether the condensation is ALOWC, and return that answer.

Each step in this algorithm takes time O(m + n), so the overall runtime is O(m + n) as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant answer! Can you share your thought process while solving these kinds of problems? How do you proceed to check if the algorithm you are thinking of is actually correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

Templatetypedef's answer is correct, but not linear time. In the worst case, the condensed graph is the same as the original. Therefore, the removal of each source node could make |V| - k comparisons, where k is the number of nodes already removed. So, |V| + (|V| - 1) + (|V| - 2) + ... + 1 = |V|(|V| + 1)/2. It is O(V^2 + E) because of the source node removal process.

Comment: Please use code sample tool in your answers